# Get bundle's default publication status

Tags: 8

I would like to retrieve whether the bundle of a node is supposed to default to published. I am able to successfully get the bundle of the node in question.

```
$bundle = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('node_type')
      ->load($node->bundle());
```

However, I am unable to retrieve information about default status of the bundle. When I use Devel's `dsm()` function in order to see the array for `$bundle`, the "field" `[status]`, which I would have thought was the value I want, doesn't change. It remains `1`. I tried changing the publication status of the node in question as well as changing the default value for the content type publication status, but neither of these affect this value.

How can I get the bundle's default publication status? What am I missing?

Edit: I am also now using `$bundle->get('status')` to get the specific field referenced above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is stored in the field's config, rather than the node type's. Currently it's not possible to get that value without having a node to work with.

This is alluded to in [`NodeTypeForm::form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeTypeForm.php/function/NodeTypeForm%3A%3Aform/8.6.x) (and also the `save()` method of the same class):

```
if ($this->operation == 'add') {
  $form['#title'] = $this->t('Add content type');
  $fields = $this->entityManager->getBaseFieldDefinitions('node');
  // Create a node with a fake bundle using the type's UUID so that we can
  // get the default values for workflow settings.
  // @todo Make it possible to get default values without an entity.
  //   https://www.drupal.org/node/2318187
  $node = $this->entityManager->getStorage('node')->create(['type' => $type->uuid()]);
}
else {
  $form['#title'] = $this->t('Edit %label content type', ['%label' => $type->label()]);
  $fields = $this->entityManager->getFieldDefinitions('node', $type->id());
  // Create a node to get the current values for workflow settings fields.
  $node = $this->entityManager->getStorage('node')->create(['type' => $type->id()]);
}
```

It goes on to set the options arrays for the checkboxes using that node:

```
$workflow_options = [
  'status' => $node->status->value,
  'promote' => $node->promote->value,
  'sticky' => $node->sticky->value,
  'revision' => $type->isNewRevision(),
];
```

So, for now at least, you'll probably need to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! To get the exact value I wanted, for those who want the condensed answer, I simply added the following line, based on your answer. `$default_status = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->create(['type' => $node->bundle()])->status->value;` where `$node` is the node of the bundle for which I want the default value.